# How to fix error: Blogdown::serve_site() timeout error?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio, hugo

Trying to create my blogdown website with Hugo Apéro in Rmarkdown when it renders the page it produces an error like the following:

> rmarkdown::render_site()
> Start building sites…
> hugo v0.115.4-dc9524521270f81d1c038ebbb200f0cfa3427cc5+extended windows/amd64 BuildDate=2023-07-20T06:49:57Z VendorInfo=gohugoio

Total in 360ms
Error: error building site: "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Documents\myrepo\Webhenry\content\collection\day01\03-distill\index.md:24:4": failed to parse Markdown attributes; you may need to quote the values

I clarify that I have the latest version of hugo updated:
blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.115.4’

I was redirected to the address that suggested the error "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Documents\myrepo\Webhenry\content\collection\day01\03-distill\index.md:24:4"
and I found in line 24:

24 `{=html} 25 <!-- --> 26`

I'm not sure why this block of code is causing the error, as it appears to be a simple block of code with the language set to HTML. I don't see attributes in this line that require citation.

Could anyone help me identify the problem and provide a solution? Is it possible that there are other errors in my Markdown file that could be causing this problem?

I appreciate any advice or suggestions you can offer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve your problem ? I am facing the same issue.